# Android app launcher icon size issue

Tags: android, icons, launcher

Our app manifest launcher icon in xml file drawable\icon.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<bitmap xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:src="@drawable/icon_beta"/>
```

The xml file gets modified at build time to point to either icon_beta or icon_prod.

```
<application android:icon="@drawable/icon"
```

Both icon_beta.png and icon_prod.png exist in all resolutions. However, we found that on xhdpi device hdpi icon is used instead of xhdpi. If we reference the icon directly without xml file

```
<application android:icon="@drawable/icon_beta"
```

then correct xhdpi icon is used.

Why using the xml drawable affects which resolution is used?

Comment: This is very interesting, how did you test this?  on emulator (what api)?  or a device (what devive)? I'm going to try someting like this on my n10 and get back here

Comment: Why modify an xml file instead the manifest file itself? Both are xml and both should be easily modified in the same way during built process.

Comment: @warrenfaith,  I agree,  but perhaps the manifest file is under source control as editing it directly would cause repo commits and updates needlessly?  And a lesser important xml could always be generated/ignored a bit easier.

Comment: Well how ever they change the icon.xml it would be easy to change the manifest, too. And the built server should just read from git and not push. So checkout/pull with force enabled to override every possible generated change and it will work easily. @user1744147 could you double check that you have all 4 dpi folders with both versions? Also how do you test it?

Comment: Yes, I tested this on actual device, such as Nexus 7.

Comment: I cannot change just manifest since the icon is referenced in zillion places. So the build server just modifies the xml file and either beta or prod icon is used everywhere.

Answer (score 1):

I found that, specifically for the Nexus 7, specifying a resource in drawable-tvdpi the same dimensions as drawable-hdpi (72p) fixes this issue.  I don't know why :(.

Answer (score 0):

The nexus 7 is not an xhdpi device, it has a PPI of 216 and is well within the hdpi 240 DPI bucket.

See this image (fig 1 from http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html )

[image: dpi bucket ranges]

Comment: If I reference icon png file the xhdpi icon is used.